# Excel VBA Next Without For

Tags: excel, vba

The syntax of a new language can be difficult to mater. I am a 1 day old to VBA excel Wonder Where I am going wrong below.

Trying to color rows in an selection  of Cells made by the user alternatively

```
Sub color()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim P As Object
    I = 1
    R = Selection
    For Each P In R
        If I Mod 2 = 0 Then
             P.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        Else
            P.Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        I = I + 1
    Next P
End Sub
```

The error I get is Next Without for

Comment: Add `End if` before `Next P`!

Comment: R is a range. You have to use `Set` to Set a range

Comment: @KazJaw: + 1 This time I checked the comments :P

Answer (score 1):

Siddarth, his question was "The error I get is Next Without for". I had corrected the error by adding "End IF". Anyways here is the correct code: ---

```
Sub color()
  Dim R As Range
  Dim I As Integer
    Dim P As Object
  I = 1
  'R = ActiveWindow.Selection
  For Each P In ActiveWindow.Selection
      If I Mod 2 = 0 Then
           P.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
      Else
          P.Interior.ColorIndex = 40
      End If
      I = I + 1
    Next P
 End Sub
```

6 and 7th line also can be changed as below:

```
  Set R = ActiveWindow.Selection
  For Each P In R
```

Comment: You still haven't understood what I am trying to say... Read my comment below the question

Comment: Also no need for `dim P as object`